# Overlapping Transactions

Tags: transaction, database-theory

Apolgies in advance if this has been discussed before, or is even fundamental enough for it to be outlined on, say, Wikipedia. I just felt that asking would be more efficient!

Anyway, I want to ask about transactions, from a theoretical point of view. In particular, say we have two (or more) users looking at a dataset and the following occur at the times indicated (`tX`):

```
t0   User1 starts a transaction
t1   User2 starts a transaction
t2   User1 runs a DML operation on the dataset
t3   User2 runs a different DML on the same dataset
t4   User1's operation finishes and is committed
t5   User2 commits
```

My question is: how do the DML operations run between `User1` and `User2` interact with each other? Does the operation started at `t2` by `User1` operate on the data as it was defined at the start of their transaction (i.e., at `t0`), and likewise for `User2`'s operation, so that there is no interaction? Or, if say `User1` committed their operation after `User2`'s transaction had started but before they had started their operation, would the data `User2` was looking at be updated respectively? Moreover, how is consistency maintained in the case of any conflicts?

Comment: Might be more productive to read the Wiki article on [isolation levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) then ask a more specific question if any points are unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all general cases, the second transaction will be blocked until the first one commits or rolls back. As Martin notes, your isolation level may affect this, but the entire point of ACID compliance is to keep them separate.